# Get array length of an attribut mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my situation I need the number of id in my attributs "idsProfil". I don't want all id in the attribut, just the number.

This is how I can get the publications.

```
    const publication = await this.publicationService.paginated(
      {
        $and: [
          { deletedAt: null },
        ],
        $or: [
          { profile: friends},
          { profile: req.user.profile},
        ]
      },
      {populate: [
        ['profile'],
        ['like'],
      ]},
      req.query)
```

And this the how my object like was created.

```
const LikeSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  idsProfil: {
    type: [String],
  }
})
```

I can't use pre-validate like moongose cause I use FindAndUpdate, and I can't use Save()

Comment: Do you mean that you need to set a limited number of IDs inside of idsProfik.type ?

Comment: Thank you for your help! No, I just want to get the number of id in my table. It's a counter of like

Comment: Ohh right, so the number of documents inside of your collection.

Comment: Yes exactly   @DataHearth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the number of documents existing in a collection with Mongoose, you could use [Model.estimatedDocumentCount()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.estimatedDocumentCount). It'll browse your collection with metadata.

Another way is using [Model.countDocuments()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments). BUT, this functions is not efficient on large collection due to the way that it's browsing the collection. It's scanning the entire collection and count each document, which is not efficient.